# Does anyone know why the Response Body would be empty on an HTTP Post form from IOS. It works in Android

Tags: python, ios, sockets, http, response

Hi We're trying to use this WIFI Manager (https://github.com/tayfunulu/WiFiManager/blob/master/wifimgr.py) to connect an ESP 32 device to a local wifi .

The WIFI Manager basically identifies all SSID's in the local area,  starts a web server on 192.168.4.1, displays the different networks and lets the user select the one they want to connect to.  This process is done on mobile browsers (Android or IOS phones and any browser).

This works perfectly in Android but IOS returns an empty POST response body. I used IOS Charles and can see the Response body with the correct information but it does not make it back to the server.

[Image shows Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg6W4.jpg)

[Image two shows response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHMh7.jpg)

This is what server received in Andriod (data in bold at end of stream):

client connected from ('192.168.4.3', 47754)
Request is: b'POST /configure HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.4.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Length: 39\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nOrigin: http://192.168.4.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Mobile DuckDuckGo/5 Safari/537.36\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9\r\nX-Requested-With: com.duckduckgo.mobile.android\r\nReferer: [http://192.168.4.1/\r\nAccept-Encoding](http://192.168.4.1/%5Cr%5CnAccept-Encoding): gzip, deflate\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9\r\n\r\n**ssid=mywifi&password=abcdef1234'**

This is what the server received in IOS (no data at end of stream):

client connected from ('192.168.4.2', 64482)
Request is: b'POST /configure HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.4.1\r\nOrigin: http://192.168.4.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nUpgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 DuckDuckGo/7\r\nReferer: [http://192.168.4.1/\r\nContent-Length](http://192.168.4.1/%5Cr%5CnContent-Length): 39\r\nAccept-Language: en-us\r\n\r\n'

I realize the Charles response header and data are different then the IOS paragraph above but it is the same result.  I've made tried Safari, Chrome and FF on iphone all with same results.  I've made sure that privacy setting are set to allow third party data but maybe there is another spot I missed. Provided the Form action code below (def handle_root(client) which puts up the screen to display all the local wifi networks and below that the web server start (Def start (port=80)).

Thanks, Jim

Form for user to select SSID to connect to:

```
def send_header(client, status_code=200, content_length=None ):
    client.sendall("HTTP/1.0 {} OK\r\n".format(status_code))
    client.sendall("Content-Type: text/html\r\n")
    if content_length is not None:
       client.sendall("Content-Length: {}\r\n".format(content_length))
    client.sendall("\r\n")

def handle_root(client):
wlan_sta.active(True)
ssids = sorted(ssid.decode('utf-8') for ssid, *_ in wlan_sta.scan())
send_header(client)
client.sendall("""\
    <html>
        <h1 style="color: #5e9ca0; text-align: center;">
            <span style="color: #ff0000;">
                Wi-Fi Client Setup
            </span>
        </h1>
        <form action="configure" method="post">
            <table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <tbody>
""")
while len(ssids):
    ssid = ssids.pop(0)
    client.sendall("""\
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="radio" name="ssid" value="{0}" />{0}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
    """.format(ssid))
client.sendall("""\
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password:</td>
                        <td><input name="password" type="password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <hr />
        <h5>
            <span style="color: #ff0000;">
                Your ssid and password information will be saved into the
                "%(filename)s" file in your ESP module for future usage.
                Be careful about security!
            </span>
        </h5>
        <hr />
        <h2 style="color: #2e6c80;">
            Some useful infos:
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Original code from <a href="https://github.com/cpopp/MicroPythonSamples"
                    target="_blank" rel="noopener">cpopp/MicroPythonSamples</a>.
            </li>
            <li>
                This code available at <a href="https://github.com/tayfunulu/WiFiManager"
                    target="_blank" rel="noopener">tayfunulu/WiFiManager</a>.
            </li>
        </ul>
    </html>
""" % dict(filename=NETWORK_PROFILES))
client.close()

def start(port=80):
global server_socket

addr = socket.getaddrinfo('0.0.0.0', port)[0][-1]

stop()

wlan_sta.active(True)
wlan_ap.active(True)

wlan_ap.config(essid=ap_ssid, password=ap_password, authmode=ap_authmode)

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(addr)
server_socket.listen(1)

print('Connect to WiFi ssid ' + ap_ssid + ', default password: ' + ap_password)
print('and access the ESP via your favorite web browser at 192.168.4.1.')
print('Listening on:', addr)

while True:
    if wlan_sta.isconnected():
        return True

    client, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('client connected from', addr)
    try:
        client.settimeout(5.0)

        request = b""
        try:
            while "\r\n\r\n" not in request:
                request += client.recv(512)
        except OSError:
            pass

        print("Request is: {}".format(request))
        if "HTTP" not in request:  # skip invalid requests
            continue

        # version 1.9 compatibility
        try:
            url = ure.search("(?:GET|POST) /(.*?)(?:\\?.*?)? HTTP", request).group(1).decode("utf-8").rstrip("/")
        except Exception:
            url = ure.search("(?:GET|POST) /(.*?)(?:\\?.*?)? HTTP", request).group(1).rstrip("/")
        print("URL is {}".format(url))

        if url == "":
            handle_root(client)
        elif url == "configure":
            handle_configure(client, request)
        else:
            handle_not_found(client, url)

    finally:
        client.close()
```

[WIFI Manager Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGXpb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  So it turns out, and maybe this is obvious to those familiar with HTTP socket protocol, but with Android mobile OS the response body is returned with the header at the end, with IOS you have to execute another "recv" to retrieve the response body.  hope this helps someone and save them weeks of digging and angst.